# W3C Iframe Validation

Tags: iframe, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm using the Facebook plugin called Activity Feed.

The URL of this plugin is:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity

Now, I'm having a problem.

When I get the code for using this plugin it comes inside an IFrame, and has a not standard attribute for Internet Explorer browsers, or at least that what I read, it's the  allowTransparency="true" attribute.

When I validate my web site with this component it shows an error, there is no attribute "allowTransparency".

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ollivanders.co%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

How can I solve it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same thing. I deleted that attribute and the iframe worked just fine without it. Cosmetically it didn't affect any of my target browsers so I can live with it. 
I *suppose* that attribute could be added via javascript if you really need it (don't know how to do this though)